# How to get result of complex query in redbeanphp

Tags: redbean

So I have this query

```
    $sql = "set @row_number := 0;
                SELECT *
                FROM (
                    SELECT user_id, @row_number := @row_number +1 pos
                    FROM user
                    ORDER BY plays DESC
                ) AS row_to_return
                WHERE user_id =  '{$_SESSION['user']->user_id}'";

    echo $sql;

    $user_pos = R::exec($sql);
```

Have tried to use exec, findAll, findRow - no result.

Answer (score 0):

This thing did the trick:

```
    $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM (
                    SELECT user_id, @row_number := @row_number +1 pos
                    FROM user
                    ORDER BY plays DESC
                ) AS row_to_return
                WHERE user_id =  '{$_SESSION['user']->user_id}'";

    $set_sql = 'set @row_number := 0';
    R::exec($set_sql);
    $user_pos = R::getRow($sql);
```